# How to append to a C++ preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

A macro like `M_PI` is pretty useful, but it defines its value as a `double`. When using it as a float, you can't write `M_PIf`, because that obviously changes the name of the macro.

*How can I append text to a macro?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (at least not without involving more macros).

You can write `float(M_PI)`, or `static_cast<float>(M_PI)` if you like verbosity.

Comment: for safety reasons, shouldn't I use `static_cast`?

Comment: @iFreilicht: Yes, definitely.

Comment: @iFreilicht: It depends what you mean by "safety", but that might be preferable if you'd rather make the cast more explicit. (Safety is only a concern when casting between reference or pointer types, where an over-lenient cast could give undefined behaviour).

Comment: I want to be sure that it works. If somebody redefines `M_PI` (for whatever wicked reason he might have) to be replaced with the constructor of a custom class, a `static_cast` would instantly fail while a functional cast could just back up t0 a `reinterpret_cast`, which could of course cause silent errors that may be undiscovered for a long time.

Comment: @iFreilicht: No, the cast won't act like `reinterpret_cast` since that only works on pointer and reference types. For numeric and class types, function-style (and C-style) casts can only perform the same conversions that `static_cast` can. But by all means use `static_cast` if you want the conversion to look more obvious.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. I will go for the more verbose option. By now you have answered more than half of my questions on SO to my fullest satisfaction :)

Comment: @iFreilicht: Since you are casting to a floating point type, there are fewer legal casts. If you were casting to an pointer or reference type, or to an integral type capable of holding a pointer, then there would be a difference between `static_cast` and c-style casts for some values of `M_PI`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define CONCATENATE_DETAIL(x, y) x##y
#define CONCATENATE(x, y) CONCATENATE_DETAIL(x, y)

CONCATENATE(M_PI,f)
```

This is more verbose than float(M_PI) and does not always work.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** Each macro has an individual definition, and you can't just append an f to it. As an alternative, of course, you could always use a second macro which is the version which ends with an f.

But **you shouldn't want to do it**, anyway. Don't use macros to define numeric constants. Use constants. They're type safe, readable and efficient. They have everything you need and no drawbacks.

Comment: I didn't define M_PI, it's from Eigen.

Answer (score 0):

You define another macro:

```
#define M_PI_F M_PI##f
```

Although `(float)M_PI` will be clearer to the reader.

Comment: Did you try it? That expands to `M_PIf`, not the desired floating-point literal.